# Twitter bootstrap - Make a table row inactive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I want to make a row in a table inactive. Even if it is easy to hack by myself and add a custom css with the same colour of the inactive elements of my current theme I think it can be handles by bootstrap itself.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've tried to add class "inactive" "disabled" to the <tr> but nothing

Comment: please share your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Bootstrap has a few elements you might find helpful:

---

Use contextual classes to change row colors:

```
<!-- On rows -->
<tr class="active">...</tr>
<tr class="success">...</tr>
<tr class="warning">...</tr>
<tr class="danger">...</tr>
<tr class="info">...</tr>

<!-- On cells (`td` or `th`) -->
<tr>
  <td class="active">...</td>
  <td class="success">...</td>
  <td class="warning">...</td>
  <td class="danger">...</td>
  <td class="info">...</td>
</tr>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-contextual-classes

---

Use contextual colors to change the color of text:

```
<p class="text-muted">...</p>
<p class="text-primary">...</p>
<p class="text-success">...</p>
<p class="text-info">...</p>
<p class="text-warning">...</p>
<p class="text-danger">...</p>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-colors

---

The disabled element is primary for form elements and buttons. Check that out here,

Answer (score 6):

I've created a custom class `table-inactive`:

```
.table-inactive td {
    background-color: #ececec;
    color: #b9b9b9;
}
```

Comment: In this case, wouldn't the selector "tr.inactive" make more sense to inactivate a whole row? Other than that, styling looks good :)

Answer (score 1):

Does the table row contain any inputs? If so, add the disabled HTML5 attribute to the input and perhaps make the text in that row greyed out to show it is inactive? Just an idea..

I.E.

```
<tr>
   <td style="color:grey;">Sample Text</td>
   <td><input type="text" disabled/></td>
</tr>
```

I have worked with Twitter Bootstrap a bit and did not see any of these features though.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4 requires you to add "table-" to the class.

```
<tr class="table-danger">...</tr>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/#contextual-classes